# ModelValidationException: Name 'AnonymousUID' cannot be used in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.AnonymousUID'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

I am using *Entity Framework* to model an existing database. One of the database tables contains a column with the same name as the table, *AnonymousUID*.

I use the [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) function *Reverse Engineer Code First* to generate the model classes and mappings. The reverse engineering procedure automatically renames the `AnonymousUID` class member (to `AnonymousUID1`) to avoid that a member name is the same as the class name. The generated model class thus looks like this:

```
public partial class AnonymousUID
{
    public string UID { get; set; }
    public string AnonymousUID1 { get; set; }
}
```

and the EF mapping constructor is implemented like this:

```
public AnonymousUIDMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.UID);

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.UID).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(64);
    this.Property(t => t.AnonymousUID1).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(64);

    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("AnonymousUID");
    this.Property(t => t.UID).HasColumnName("UID");
    this.Property(t => t.AnonymousUID1).HasColumnName("AnonymousUID");
}
```

The database context class is implemented like this:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // Constructors...

    public DbSet<AnonymousUID> AnonymousUIDs { get; set; }
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AnonymousUIDMap());
        ...
    }
}
```

This is all good and well, and the code builds without problems. But when I try to access arbitrary contents of the database:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var foos = from foo in context.Foos select foo;
    ...
}
```

the following exception is nonetheless thrown:

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException : 
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tAnonymousUID: Name: Name 'AnonymousUID' cannot be used in type
CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.AnonymousUID'. Member names cannot be the 
same as their enclosing type.
```

There is obviously some additional mapping build-up going on in `CodeFirstDatabaseSchema`, and this procedure is *not* able to avoid the class/member name clash.

- Why does this error occur? After all, the reverse engineering procedure managed to circumvent the naming issue.
- Without modifying the schema of the already established database, is there some way I can avoid this exception from being thrown?

I am using Entity Framework 6.0 (pre-release) from Nuget in a .NET Framework 4 project.

Comment: seems a long shot but you could try changing the column name to start with a lowercase 'a' - `HasColumnName("anonymousUID");`

Comment: @qujck It seemed like a long shot, but it was indeed a good one :-) It worked! Provided that the column names in the database are case insensitive, I can use whatever casing I like in the `HasColumnName` method to avoid class/member name clashes in the code. Please move your comment to the answer section and I will happily upvote and accept it :-)

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on the EF6 Beta1 build but it no longer reproes on the latest nightly build. Can you try the nightly build and confirm it was fixed? Here are the steps on how to setup a NuGet feed for nightly builds: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nightly%20Builds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I guessed at in the comment above, change the column name to start with a lowercase 'a'

```
...HasColumnName("anonymousUID");
```

Let's hope this is a pre release defect and is fixed in the RTM ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is the code you displayed the only place you're using the `AnonymousUID` name?  What is the name of your `DbSet` in the generated `DbContext`?

I built a test app, and didn't get any errors, here it in it's entirety:

```
   public partial class AnonymousUID 
    {
        [Key]
        public int UID { get; set; }
        public string AnonymousUID1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<AnonymousUID> AnonymousUIDs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AnonymousUID>()
                        .Property(a => a.AnonymousUID1)
                        .HasColumnName("AnonymousUID");

            modelBuilder.Entity<AnonymousUID>()
                .ToTable("AnonymousUID");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var model = new Model();

            var a = new AnonymousUID();

            a.AnonymousUID1 = "hello world";
            model.AnonymousUIDs.Add(a);
            model.SaveChanges();

            var applications = model.AnonymousUIDs.ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(applications.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Created this database:

[image]

It was able to create, insert, and then display the count of the table.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I have updated the question with code for my database context implementation. I am using the name `AnonymousUIDs` for the `DbSet`, so it should not be any name clash there. I notice that your `DbContext.OnModelCreating` override is implemented a little different from "my" auto-generated one, but it is not clear to me how I should change my auto-generated code and if it will indeed make a difference?

Comment: Well that's what I'm wondering - I updated my OnModelCreating on my test app to match yours exactly, and I'm not getting the error.  It really seems like it's somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but I could not rename the column because it would break legacy code. The type names that Power Tools generated are all lowercase. I changed the capitalization on the conflicting types, and it worked.

I suspect that CodeFirstDatabaseSchema is maintaining lowercase property names, but I am not sure. All I know is that changing my lowercase type names to properly capitalized type names fixed it. I hope that is helpful for someone.